# Angular 14 update; Jest; node test "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

We're updating  **Angular 13** to **Angular 14**.
What we did until now:

1. Update from **Angular 13.3.2** to **Angular 14** using `ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@14`
2. Update `eslint-plugin-jest` manually to `26.8.7`
3. Update `eslint-plugin-import` manually to `2.26.0`

After that we run node test for the project and we get the next error that didn't happened before update:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I share my **jest.config.js** for reference:

```
const esModules = ['tslib'];

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular/presets/defaults-esm',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            useESM: true,
            stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
            allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
            isolatedModules: true
        },
    },
    transform: {
        'worker\\.provider\\.ts$': ['babel-jest', { configFile: './babel-jest.config.js' }],
        '^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!${esModules.join('|')})`, 'node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!${esModules.join('|')})`],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@i3c/shared/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1',
        '^@i3c/core/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1',
        '^@i3c/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/components/$1',
        '^@i3c/utils/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/utils/$1',
        '^@i3c/administration/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/components/poste-source/administration/$1',
        '^@i3c/exploitation/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/components/poste-source/exploitation/$1',
        '^@i3c/layout/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/components/layout/$1',
        '^@i3c/model/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/model/$1',
        '^@i3c/spec/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/spec/$1',
        '^@i3c/animations$': '<rootDir>/src/app/utils/animations',
        '^environments/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/environments/$1',
        'tslib': 'tslib/tslib.es6.js',
        'ng2-charts': '<rootDir>/node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2020/ng2-charts.mjs',
        '@angular/core/testing': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs',
        '@angular/platform-browser/testing': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2020/testing.mjs',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2020/testing.mjs',
    },
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '/src/spec/testing-utils/'
    ],
    verbose: false,
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: false,
    collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.ts'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got the same issue while trying to update from Angular 13 to 14,